# Fatal error of method while declaring new Class

Tags: php

I've got this weird error.
I've got DB class and Live class. the Live class is not extends DB class.
I can't understand why when i declare the New Live this happened.
The Errors is:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Live::$isOff in /home/main/Database/DB.class.php on line 570

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Live::Query() in /home/main/Database/DB.class.php on line 574
```

This is what i got on this line:

**ON DB.Class.php**

```
public function setCharset($charset) {
    if (self::$isOff){
        return false;
    }
    self::$charset = $charset;
    self::Query("SET NAMES '".$charset."'");
    return self;
}
```

**ON Live.Class.php**

```
class Live
{

   protected $PaypalLogo = '';

   protected $isQA = null;
   protected $siteURL = null;

   public function __construct() {

    DB::setCharset("utf8");//Setting charset here and that is gives Fatal Error.

    if (strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "ba.")) {
        $this->isQA = true;
        $this->siteURL = "http://ba.live.com";

    }
    else {

        $this->isQA = false;
        $this->siteURL = "http://www.live.com/";
    }
  }
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Neither the property or method are defined in `Live`

Comment: no there is no method  and no property in Live Class

Comment: Please post the full db

Comment: I found the problem. what i needed to do, it is get instance of DB  and then  call the setCharset function, because it was taked $this of Live and not of DB. thanks for help any way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem. it was because there are no instance of DB and because of this, it was take the instance of Live .